# How to create object for webview from one controller to another controller

Tags: iphone, ios, webview, viewcontroller

In my application i have 8 files

ApplicationDelegate.h,**ApplicationController.h** and  .m file for this
RecordDelegate.h, **RecordController.h** and .m file for this

i declared webview in **Applicationcontroller**

while running the application

webview load with **main.html** file in this i have button **record** when i click the button navigate to **record.html** file here i have **record audio** and **record video** buttons,

here when,  i click to **record audio** it navigate to **RecordController.xib** file here i have completed the record operations what i want means after complete record i want to use **ApplicationController** webview .. and here i want to pass some values to javascript
in record voiddidload method i added the below code

```
ApplicationController *obj=[ApplicationController alloc]init];
[self.view addsubview:obj.Web_View];
```

it is not working any one know the reason 
Do you have any queries let me know?

Thanks

Comment: Use custom class with property of UIWebView, pass it to the Controller, before load it, or make a singleton class to share it as a global variable.

Comment: i am new to ios... can you explain little briefly?

Comment: Suppose you want to access a UIWebView property across two Controllers, and you can share it right? Make another class, but it's singleton, store this property to this class, and access it when you need it, for singleton class example, check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/145154/what-does-your-objective-c-singleton-look-like

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Navigate to Application Controller from RecordController.

Application Controller has already webview in it so synthesis webview object in RecordController and pass the value to Application Controller when you navigate.

Comment: i declared one webview in record page and here created object for Application controller like ApplicationController *obj=[ApplicationController alloc]init]; obj.Webview=WebView(record page webview) its not working

Comment: Why you are declaring webview in record page its already there in application controller so just create object of application controller and access webview property

Comment: created object for ApplicationController [self.view addSubview:obj.WebView];

Comment: This is not sufficient to identify where the problem is.

Answer (score 0):

This is a great tutorial for making a singleton: http://getsetgames.com/2009/08/30/the-objective-c-singleton/

When you want to use it you just call MySingleton.sharedMySingleton.yourVariable 
or if you want to call a method you type [[MySingleton sharedMySingleton] yourMethod]